# Multiple Window Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using SQL developer to access 2 different databases.
I have 2 connections and while working I need to open multiple windows for each database.

How does one do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You can right click on a connection and chose **'Open SQL Worksheet'** it will create another window for the existing session.
2. Use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>and select the connection from the list.

If you need to create another independent session you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> for an ongoing session.

Answer (score 3):

In preferences, go to **Database > ObjectViewer** and check the **Automatically Freeze Object Viewer Windows** checkbox.

Comment: on connection channel i right clicked the DB 
pressed open SQL Worksheet and it gave me a new instance

Answer (score 0):

**dbardelas** answer helped me, the only thing is that he missed where is Database.

Database can be found in **tools** -> **preferences**

I had similar issue as **victorien sukarieh** the only issue I had is that every conexion to a table or database was opened on top of the previous one. It didn't let me visualize multiple tables, with the answer of **dbardelas** I can open multiple table visualization.

Comment: Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post;](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).